# why imaginary part of complex variables in lapacke does not work?

Tags: c++, lapacke

I am using TDM gcc 64bit compiler in windows

My headers

```
#include "lapacke.h"
#include "lapacke_config.h"
```

I have a simple code like this

```
lapack_complex_double x = {8.0, 6.0};
printf( "x =  (%6.2f,%6.2f)\n", x.real, x.imag);
```

first of all, it gives me the following error and warning

```
warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
lapack_complex_double x = {8.0, 6.0};
&
error: request for member 'real' in something, not a structure or union
printf( "x =  (%6.2f,%6.2f)\n", x.real, x.imag);
```

I changed the code as follows

```
lapack_complex_double x = {8.0, 6.0};
printf( "x =  (%6.2f,%6.2f)\n", lapack_complex_double_real(x),
lapack_complex_double_imag(x) );
```

the code was compiled with the same mentioned warning, but the result is

```
x =  (  8.00,  0.00)
```

It seems that the warning is an important error.

Comment: The warning probably is because that's not how you're really supposed to initialize variables of that type?

Comment: You've got reasonable expectations, but they're reasonable for C++. `lapacke.h` however is a C header.

Comment: Given [this](http://www.netlib.org/lapack//explore-html/d0/d87/lapacke__config_8h_ad3fccfa336e6375f856b0ea83fb28343.html#ad3fccfa336e6375f856b0ea83fb28343), I would also take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Complex_floating_types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that warning is an important error it's telling you that's not how you initialise complex types using the lapacke library. You need to use:

```
x = lapack_make_complex_float(8.0, 6.0);
```

see the example in this question. This should get this working for you.

[Compiling lapacke example code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541401/compiling-lapacke-example-code)

Comment: Corrected, but still, I can not understand why these expressions (x.real, x.imag) lead the error "request for member 'real' in something, not a structure or union" in compiling

Comment: while it (a[i*lda+j].real) has been used in the standard examples of lapacke in function "print_matrix". I should change them also for compiling.